# Possible to find instances of elements with certain names regardless of position

Tags: xml, xpath

I have this XML and I am trying to extract serial numbers from it.

However, the serial numbers aren't on the same level so I find it hard to accomplish it since the tool I am using requires me to do it with one single XPATH expression.

```
<rpc-reply>
    <chassis-inventory>
        <chassis junos:style="inventory">
            <name>Chassis</name>
            <serial-number>AAABBB</serial-number>
            <description>SRX220H</description>
            <chassis-module>
                <name>Routing Engine</name>
                <version>REV 23</version>
                <part-number>750-031175</part-number>
                <serial-number>XXXYYY</serial-number>
                <description>RE-SRX220H</description>
            </chassis-module>
            <chassis-module>
                <name>FPC 0</name>
                <description>FPC</description>
                <chassis-sub-module>
                    <name>PIC 0</name>
                    <description>8x GE Base PIC</description>
                </chassis-sub-module>
            </chassis-module>
            <chassis-module>
                <name>Power Supply 0</name>
            </chassis-module>
        </chassis>
    </chassis-inventory>
    <cli>
        <banner></banner>
    </cli>
</rpc-reply>
```

The data I wish to extract is:

```
<name>Chassis</name>
<serial-number>AAABBB</serial-number>

<name>Routing Engine</name>
<serial-number>XXXYYY</serial-number>
```

Any ideas?

Kind regards,

Patrik

Comment: Show your attempts and current output. Also specify `XPath` version your tool use

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment! I don't have much to show because I could not find any "position independent" way of finding the data. My thoughts was to retrieve all "levels" which has *name* and *serial-number* and display them. The tool is proprietary third party, so I actually don't know which version it is.

Comment: You've not stated the basis for choosing those elements in terms of the XML.  Until you do so, all you'll get will be guesses that may or may not work for you in general.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use below `XPath` expression to get required output:

```
//chassis-module[1]//preceding::*[name()=("name", "serial-number")]
```

Comment: I usually try https://codebeautify.org/Xpath-Tester for testing XPath and it did not work there at least. Will look into what preceeding does. Thanks!

Comment: This XPath requires XPath 2.0.  Also, OP has not stated the criteria for the elements to be selected, so the problem is too underspecified as it currently stands.

Answer (score 0):

We ended up "solving" it like this. Not sure if this is pure XPath or not, but it worked:

```
/rpc-reply//chassis | /rpc-reply//chassis-module
```

Thanks for all the attempts to decipher my poorly written XPath question!

/Patrik

Comment: The output of your expression is not even close to required output claimed in question :))

Comment: Haha, agreed! But considering our lack of experience we just went for the first thing we could work with. :) Question will remain unanswered.